# Null List attribute when API get

Tags: c#, api, get, null

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why I'm getting null attribute value after API get.

**Usertraining model**

```
public class UserTraining
{
    public int UserTrainingId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Training Training { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    //Value2 is time in min
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public int BurnedCalories { get; set; }
    public int AvgHR { get { if (SessionTraining.Count > 0) { return Convert.ToInt32(SessionTraining.Average(s => s.HeartRate)); } else return 0; } }
    public virtual ICollection<SessionTraining> SessionTraining { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

**Activity model**

```
public class Activity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserTrainingId { get; set; }
    public Movement Movement { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StopTime { get; set; }
    public int AvgHR { get; set; }
    public int BurnedKcal { get; set; }
    public virtual UserTraining UserTraining { get; set; }


    public Activity(DateTime start, Movement movement, DateTime stop)
    {
        StartTime = start;
        Movement = movement;
        StopTime = stop;
    }

}
public enum Movement
{
    Layover,
    Walk,
    Run
}
```

**PUT for activities**

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/usertraining2/addactivity/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddActivity(int id)
    {

        var usertraining = db.UserTrainings.Where(u => u.UserTrainingId == id).SingleOrDefault();
        var sessionsTraining = db.SessionTrainings.Where(u => u.UserTrainingId == id).ToList();
        List<Activity> activities = ActivityManager.analizeActivity(sessionsTraining);
        usertraining.Activities = activities;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(usertraining);
    }
```

**get**

```
// GET: api/UserTraining1
    public IEnumerable<UserTraining> GetUserTrainings()
    {
        var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var usertrainings = db.Set<UserTraining>().Where(u => u.UserId == userid).ToArray();
        return usertrainings;
    }
```

At first I'm putting activity in usertraining model. Put works fine and records in database adds but when i call Api get for usertraining it returns json with Activity equal null.

Comment: Can you post your GET method as well?

Comment: Does the GET method have an `Include(..)` for the activity? For example: `var usertraining = db.UserTrainings.Include(ut => ut.Activities).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserTrainingId == id);`

Comment: Get added in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DavidG already mentioned in the comments, you need to add `Include()` to load the referenced list. Change your GET method to something like this

```
// GET: api/UserTraining1
    public IEnumerable<UserTraining> GetUserTrainings()
    {
        var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var usertrainings = db.Set<UserTraining>().Where(u => u.UserId == userid).Include(u=>u.Activities).ToArray();
        return usertrainings;
    }
```

Comment: @DavidG but still you've got my appreciation

Comment: @KrzysztofKozieł I was just trying to point out to Mats391 that it's very bad form to copy answers like that, at least without waiting a short while to see if I add it myself.